# tiJsPdf corrupt file but fine on iPhone

Tags: pdf, module, appcelerator, jspdf, appcelerator-titanium

I am using ti.jspdf to create a stock order form. When adding an image i use

```js
PDF.addImage(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'logo/logo-pdf.jpg').nativePath,'JPEG',10,13,60,14);
```

this works fine until i try to open the pdf on anything other than an iPhone.

if i take out the image the pdf opens fine on everything.  I have tried to base64 it as a large string but the port of jspdf to ti.jspdf seems to only support a file path being passed through to it.

has anyone seen / overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you try the maintainer of the module, e.g. create an issue at the [Github repo](https://github.com/AppWerft/TiJSPDF).

Comment: Your issue might also be related to the image itself. If you shared the pdf and the image file, people might analyze them.